# OpenGL Optimization

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to render 3 quads (1 bg, 2 sprites) using OpenGL. I have the following code:

```
void GLRenderer::onDrawObjects(long p_dt)
{
    float _log_last_time = ELAPSED_MS;
    fprintf(stdout, "-- starting draw: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(std::vector<queuedRenderable*>::iterator itr = m_displayList.begin();
        itr != m_displayList.end();
        itr++)
    {
        Sprite* spriteToRender = (*itr)->m_sprite;

        float _log_last_time1 = ELAPSED_MS;
        fprintf(stdout, "---- profiling object: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time1);

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();

        // glTranslate, glRotate, glScale goes here

        fprintf(stdout, "---- transform done: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time1);
        _log_last_time1 = ELAPSED_MS;

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*itr)->m_material->m_glId);

        fprintf(stdout, "---- set material done: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time1);
        _log_last_time1 = ELAPSED_MS;

        unsigned listIds[] = {
            (*itr)->m_mesh->m_glId
        };
        glCallLists(1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, listIds);

        fprintf(stdout, "---- draw mesh done: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time1);
        _log_last_time1 = ELAPSED_MS;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "-- flushing to card: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time);
    _log_last_time = ELAPSED_MS;

    glFlush();
    glFinish();

    fprintf(stdout, "-- flush done: %.4f, dTime: %.4f\n", ELAPSED_MS, ELAPSED_MS - _log_last_time);
    _log_last_time = ELAPSED_MS;
}
```

And I'm getting the following results in console:

```
-- starting draw: 24000.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- profiling object: 24014.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- transform done: 24033.0000, dTime: 19.0000
---- set material done: 24046.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- draw mesh done: 24066.0000, dTime: 1.0000
---- profiling object: 24084.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- transform done: 24102.0000, dTime: 18.0000
---- set material done: 24120.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- draw mesh done: 24305.0000, dTime: 164.0000
---- profiling object: 24319.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- transform done: 24338.0000, dTime: 19.0000
---- set material done: 24356.0000, dTime: 0.0000
---- draw mesh done: 24375.0000, dTime: 2.0000
-- flushing to card: 24389.0000, dTime: 389.0000
-- flush done: 24424.0000, dTime: 18.0000
```

As you can see, the drawing of the 2nd quad is taking very long (164ms). I have no idea why is that as they are all quads. I've also checked the texture (if that is relevant), but it is a lot smaller than the bg (1st quad). If it is of any relevance, I think the first quad should draw longer, not the second.

I'm fairly new to OpenGL (I have done a lot of opengl in the past, but just beginner stuff) so I have *some* idea of what I'm doing. I'm just not sure how I can optimize this further to remove that 164ms process.

How can I remove or minimize that 164ms process?

I have to note that I am using an Intel Atom with intel GMA 450 machine.

Comment: You sure there's not an issue with the texture format? Also, is it N^2 with/height?

Comment: ELAPSED_MS is ((((float)clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000.0f)

Comment: @Grimmy thanks for the suggestion. I tried duplicate and rename the texturefile so both sprites are the same. I'm still getting the same time.

Comment: I don't think your ELAPSED_MS is in milliseconds. 19ms for  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW ); and glLoadIdentity(); is incredible. An entire frame of a complex game running at 60fps takes 16.6ms.

Comment: @JarrodSmith I'm also doing some transformations there. I just removed them to minimize the code. Also, i'm running this on an intel atom 1.3ghz (i think) with intel gma 450.

Comment: It's still implausible. 10000 transforms would not take 19ms. Verify your timing method. e.g. Does it really take 24 seconds before you see "-- starting draw:" printed?

Comment: The absurd timings may be due to the `printf`s, assuming they're going to a console, which is usually line-buffered (i.e., triggers a flush at every newline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that this mysterious `ELAPSED_MS` macro were a cycle-accurate CPU counter. I rather doubt that it is, since it seems to jump in large millisecond increments, but let's pretend that this is the case.

Your methodology for profiling OpenGL is *completely wrong*. You are not measuring the time it takes to render a quad. You are measuring the time it takes for `glFinish` to complete. There's no guarantee that `glFinish` will return the moment the quad finishes rendering. Indeed, it could be waiting quite a while, possibly for a thread task switch or something. Who knows.

The point is that your methods for profiling are not reliable. Please stop using them. The only accurate ways of getting profiling data for actual rendering operations in OpenGL are to either employ [timer queries](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Timer_Query#Timer_queries) (which are specifically designed to test how long it takes operations on the GPU to complete) or to use [proprietary extensions](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/performance_monitor.txt).

Micro-profiling (like profiling the time it takes to draw a quad) is very difficult to do right. Quad drawing in particular is generally worthless to bother profiling.

> ELAPSED_MS is ((((float)clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000.0f)

That's so not helping. Because even if your methods were good, `clock` is *not* a reliable method for doing any form of timing. You have to use either [platform-specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [calls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html), or a platform neutral library like [C++11's chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (or the Boost equivalent).

Comment: +1 But, maybe update your answer to distinguish more clearly between CPU time due to OpenGL API calls (which is an important consideration), and rendering time on the GPU interpreting the command buffer.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I see. I was using QueryPerformanceCounter() before, I just stopped using it for this particular code. but anyway...  So what you are saying is that by the time it registers the 164.0, it may be doing something else not totally related to drawing the mesh? I thought as much, I just wasn't so sure. Thanks for the help. I'll fix the profiling code and take a look at it again.